# Django-CMS: is there a way to remove page history?

Tags: django, django-cms

In django-cms I see page history (when page was created and modified). I want to send my project to somebody but I don't want him to see project history including pages history.

Is there anyway I can remove page history (and other things' histories) without recreating the page (I have tons of pages)

Answer (score 1):

Assuming you mean the action log in Django's admin, which is storied in a model called `LogEntry`, here's how to delete all of that data:

```
from django.contrib.admin.models import LogEntry
LogEntry.objects.all().delete()
```

To do this manually, you could run those two statements in a Django-aware shell, which you can get with the following shell command at your project root:

```
python manage.py shell
```

Comment: Yeah, most of the history is deleted but it looks like django-cms pages' histories are stored somewhere else, because they remained http://img689.imageshack.us/img689/5880/3f3r.png and from every logs, I want to delete this log the most